# Proper location of Oracle ORDS when installed on Tomcat and Apex on Linux OL8

Tags: linux, oracle, tomcat, apex

I am trying to install Oracle Apex in AWS EC2 on Linux with the 19c database on one EC2 server and the Tomcat on a separate server.

my Database server = mando
my Tomcat server = r2d2

I have successfully installed Tomcat on r2d2.
I have successfully installed Oracle 19c on mando.

I can connect to each separately just fine.

I am confused about whether or not I should install ORDS on the database (mando) or tomcat (r2d2)?

I have read Oracle install instructions as well as Oracle-Base and other instructions but it is still not clear to me.

I think I need to install Apex on the DB server (mando) but in reading through the docs I'm beginning to wonder of I should put Apex and ORDS on the Tomcat server.

In the past I used the monolithic pl/sql gateway for development and another team installed the production systems.

Please reply with your advice if at all possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"APEX" is a set of stored procedures that is installed in the database. "ORDS" is a Java application that is installed on Tomcat and talks to APEX in the database. I wrote a guide on this a couple of years ago. Doesn't sound like you'd need the high availability or header authentication parts, but the initial setup is largely the same. It might add to your understanding, anyway. See here:

- https://pmdba.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ha-oracle-ords-apex-with-http-header-authentication.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the fast response. This is an excellent guide that you have put together. Thanks for sharing it.